# Get_Actions EOSFLARE API

Tags: python, post, eos

I'm trying to retrieve some data from EOS blockchain using APIs ([eosflare](https://eosflare.io/api)). I tried following the first example for the `get_actions` method but I keep getting an error response.
My code:

```
import requests # Requests: HTTP for Humans

url = "https://api.eosflare.io/v1/eosflare/get_actions/"
data = {"account_name": "yupcreators1", "pos":30, "offset":5}
r = requests.post(url, data)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.encoding)
print(r.text)
```

but I don't understand why I get this response when I print `r.text`:

```
{"err_code":10,"err_msg":"Error: ($.pos: \"30\") ✖ (type: number)"}
```

How can I solve this? Am I not passing `pos` and `offset` arguments as numbers already?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [example on the site](https://eosflare.io/api) looks like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"account_name":"eosflareiobp", "pos":-30, "offset":-5}' https://api.eosflare.io/v1/eosflare/get_actions
```

Notice that pos and offset are both negative numbers.

--Jacob